# Item not showing up correctly without margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

In my android project I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and have a Toolbar. when I'm trying to set a layout file for being my Navigation Drawer Header, with any layout frames (Relative and Linear Layouts) I should set a margin value to items to show them correctly and in the frame of  device screen!

here is my layout file that contains Navigation Drawer Header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_intro"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_app_name"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Activity layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="end"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view"
    >



</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="*.*.*.MainActivity">
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/toolbar_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/enter_something"
            android:text="Something"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/bottom_border"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/searchField_height"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gradiant"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Style file :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="intro" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#569dd5</item>

</style>
```

[here is the result that my logo is not showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrMsR.png)
Is it normal and I must set a margin to my logo or something is wrong?

Comment: Looks like your `Drawerlayout` also covering the status Bar size . add the layout.xml of activity and style.

Comment: @ADM thank you; Added!

Comment: Try to remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `NavigationView`.

Comment: @ADM by removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from **android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout** problem solved! Thank you.

Comment: haha . i miss  judge it ..Bravo . Answer your  own question .

Comment: @ADM I'm not very familiar with stackoverflow award system. you got the main idea and the write answer :-)

Comment: You will soon aware of it . An answer can also help others if someone having same problem with similar title.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` :